# How to access TemplateRef on the component of Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

> Component TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    if(somecondition)
        // This is the line of code that wont work
        this.openModal(#tempName);
}
```

> Component HTML

```
<ng-template #tempName>
    I got some content here
</ng-template>
```

this.openModal(#tempName) -> How do i get access to the ngTemplate tempName here?

Comment: You can use `@ViewChild('tempName')`

Comment: How do I implement @ViewChild into the parameter of the function:
LINE:
this.openModal(@ViewChild('suggestionModule'));

ERROR in ....component.ts(44,20): error TS1135: Argument expression expected.
....component.ts(44,50): error TS1146: Declaration expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flyn you put in your code

```
@ViewChild('tempName') mymodal: ElementRef;
//You can NOT use this.mymodal at ngInit, the early time you can use is in ngAfterViewInit
ngAfterViewInit()
{
 if (somecondition)
   this.openModal(mymodal);
}
```

Comment: You can access the ViewChild and ContentChild in `ngOnInit` as long as they are static e.g. not part of a dynamic directive like *ngFor. Explanation github.com/angular/angular/issues/19872#issuecomment-338703562. Think we use `TemplateRef` rather than `ElementRef` when referencing an `ng-template`